# class Profile has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Although [this suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994552/1730621) using model.Models for models to have the Meta attribute, I get the above mentioned error of ***no attribute error  '_meta'*** despite that.

*In models.py*:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=LENGTH)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=LENGTH)

    def __str__(self):
        print self.username
```

*In forms.py*:

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['username', 'password']
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput,
        }
```

*In views.py*:

```
class LoginFormView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'pv_ui/login_form.html'
```

The traceback can be viewed below:

```
Traceback:
File "/home/tilaprimera/.virtualenvs/nano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/tilaprimera/.virtualenvs/nano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/tilaprimera/.virtualenvs/nano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/tilaprimera/.virtualenvs/nano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/tilaprimera/PycharmProjects/djwork/pv/pv/urls.py" in <module>
  19.                            r'^nano/', include('pv_ui.urls')
File "/home/tilaprimera/.virtualenvs/nano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  28.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/home/tilaprimera/PycharmProjects/djwork/pv/pv_ui/urls.py" in <module>
  2. from views import LoginFormView, UploadServer #, UploadFormView,
File "/home/tilaprimera/PycharmProjects/djwork/pv/pv_ui/views.py" in <module>
  10. from .forms import LoginForm, UploadForm#, UploadFormSet
File "/home/tilaprimera/PycharmProjects/djwork/pv/pv_ui/forms.py" in <module>
  10. class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
File "/home/tilaprimera/.virtualenvs/nano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __new__
  284.                                       opts.help_texts, opts.error_messages)
File "/home/tilaprimera/.virtualenvs/nano/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in fields_for_model
  184.     opts = model._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /nano/login/
Exception Value: class Profile has no attribute '_meta''
```

Comment: Did you have the `Profile` class being not inherited from `models.Model` before? Also, show your import statements in models.py and forms.py. Thanks.

Comment: Rather I had a form made before based on this model Profile, a ProfileForm. However, on removing the code for this ProfileForm too, this problem persists.

Comment: I fixed my import and it works now.